# socket programming server in C

Tags: c, sockets

I'm currently learning socket programming in C on linux system. I got a sample code of server, and I'm having problem of running it properly.   It looks like this:

```
/* A simple server in the internet domain using TCP
   The port number is passed as an argument */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#define MAXCONNECTION 100 // maximum number of simultaneously connection allowed
const char CONTENTDIR[]="./contentdir" ; // this is the directory where keep all the files for requests
void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

void httpWorker(int *);// This function will handle request
char * fType(char *);
char * responseHeader(int, char *);// function that builds response header
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
     socklen_t clilen;
     char buffer[256];
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     int n;
     if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
     }
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     portno = atoi(argv[1]);
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
              error("ERROR on binding");
     listen(sockfd,MAXCONNECTION);
    while(1){
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
     newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
     if (newsockfd < 0) error("ERROR on accept");
    httpWorker(&newsockfd);//worker to fulfillthe request
    }

    close(sockfd);
     return 0; 
}

void httpWorker(int *sockfd){//sockfd contains all the information
    int newsockfd = *sockfd;// create a local variable for sockfd 
    char buffer[256];// we will read the data in this buffer
    char *token;// local variable to split the request to get the filename 
    bzero(buffer,256);// intialize the buffer data to zero
    char fileName[50];
    char homedir[50];
    char * type;
    strcpy(homedir,CONTENTDIR);// directory where files are stored.
    char *respHeader; //response header
    // start reading the message from incoming conenction
     if (read(newsockfd,buffer,255) < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
     //get the requested file part of the request
     token = strtok(buffer, " ");// split string into token seperated by " "
     token = strtok(NULL, " ");// in this go we read the file name that needs to be sent
     strcpy(fileName,token);

    // get the complete filename 
    if(strcmp(fileName,"/")==0) // if filename is not provided then we will send index.html
        strcpy(fileName,strcat(homedir,"/index.html"));
    else
        strcpy(fileName,strcat(homedir,fileName));    
     type = fType(fileName);// get file type
    //open file and ready to send 
    FILE *fp;
    int file_exist=1;
    fp=fopen(fileName, "r"); 
    if (fp==NULL) file_exist=0; 
    respHeader = responseHeader(file_exist,type);
    if ((send(newsockfd, respHeader,strlen(respHeader), 0) == -1) || (send(newsockfd,"\r\n", strlen("\r\n"), 0) == -1))
                        perror("Failed to send bytes to client");   

    free(respHeader);// free the allocated memory (note: the memory is allocated in responseheader function)

    if (file_exist){
       char filechar[1];
       while((filechar[0]=fgetc(fp))!=EOF){    
         if(send(newsockfd,filechar,sizeof(char),0) == -1) perror("Failed to send bytes to client");       
       } 
   }
  else{
       if (send(newsockfd,"<html> <HEAD><TITLE>404 Not Found</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>Not Found</BODY></html> \r\n", 100, 0) == -1)
          perror("Failed to send bytes to client");          
      }

     close(newsockfd);
}


// function below find the file type of the file requested
char * fType(char * fileName){
     char * type; 
      char * filetype = strrchr(fileName,'.');// This returns a pointer to the first occurrence of some character in the string 
      if((strcmp(filetype,".htm"))==0 || (strcmp(filetype,".html"))==0)
            type="text/html";
      else if((strcmp(filetype,".jpg"))==0)
            type="image/jpeg";
      else if(strcmp(filetype,".gif")==0)
            type="image/gif";
      else if(strcmp(filetype,".txt")==0)
            type="text/plain";
      else
            type="application/octet-stream";

return type;
}

//buildresponseheader
char * responseHeader(int filestatus, char * type){
   char statuscontent[256] = "HTTP/1.0";
   if(filestatus==1){
            strcat(statuscontent," 200 OK\r\n");
            strcat(statuscontent,"Content-Type: ");
            strcat(statuscontent,type);
            strcat(statuscontent,"\r\n");
        }
   else {
            strcat(statuscontent,"404 Not Found\r\n");
            //send a blank line to indicate the end of the header lines   
            strcat(statuscontent,"Content-Type: ");
            strcat(statuscontent,"NONE\r\n");
        } 
   char * returnheader =malloc(strlen(statuscontent)+1);
   strcpy(returnheader,statuscontent);
   return returnheader;
}
```

What I've done was to build a sub directory called contentdir  under the folder where I put this server.c file, then I tried to get connetion from my browser ( I guess it doesn't matter with the browser). I just typically ran it by ./server 8080 and put localhost:8080/(and whatever the name of files in contentdir). It shows me black screen on the browser instead of the file contents. It stops connecting after reached MAXCONNECTION attmepts, I guess. I have tried html and jpg files, both no work.

Can someone help me to figure it out please?

Comment: Try hitting it with `curl -v <url>` to see the HTTP traffic. You have at least one bug - no space before `404 Not Found`

Comment: I would start populating the code with debug printfs, especially in key points such as the full path generation, the response header sending etc, and then I would run `./server 8080 > log.txt`. That would be a good way to restrict the circle.

Comment: A good way to start learning socket programming is by 1st mastering sockets with simple servers, like echo server. Your server tries to do HTTP while in the code there are too many basic C coding errors (like passing socket file descriptor `int` by pointer) and socket handling errors (like not handling the return values of `send` and `recv` correctly). In other words, a just born baby cannot play tennis before it learns how to roll, crawl, walk and run. You seem to going from beginner C to HTTP server and that is quite a leap.

Comment: Yeah... which site did you download this thing from?  Remove it from your search history and try  to find another example written by someone who understands the TCP streaming that HTTP is built on:(